# Javascript If condition check on window load

Tags: javascript, function, window, onload

I am facing a js error.
But what I see is js is perfectly fine

```
window.onload = function() {
    var check = 'false';
    if (check == 'true') {
        var disableFlowCheck = ; //this will not come in case of fail
        if (disableFlowCheck && document.getElementById("submitlin")) {
            document.getElementById("submitlin").disabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This looks pretty good. this condition shouldn't be executed at all.
But What i see, the executing the if condition is getting executed, which shouldn't be.

Comment: `I am facing a js error`: What is the error? Also, not sure if that is the error you speak of but `var disableFlowCheck = ;` is not going to compile, you either assign a value or remove the `=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var disableFlowCheck = ; //This is syntax Error

// change to 

var disableFlowCheck = "";

// Or 

var disableFlowCheck = true;
```

Note: You have to assign variable to some value , or just define to any type variable you want (array,boolean) or just remove it

Comment: I know. but I am getting the assigned value from request. If it's not present request, it will be blank. That's the reason I placed if condition

Comment: He'll probably want `var disableFlowCheck = false;` instead of `true`.

Comment: @NitinGurram Then you have to assign marked variable with server side scripting language. For example in case of php `(var disableFlowCheck = "<?php echo "value"; ?>";)`

Comment: I think I have done workaround. I didn't know that it's not going to compile like that :)